# Socket.IO with Cordova not working on Device

Tags: angularjs, cordova, socket.io, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an Apache Cordova app with Ionic Framework that should communicate through a WebSocket and I use the Socket.Io library for it. Now when I run it on my desktop browser everything works fine but when I build for Android and test it on my Smartphone it doesn't work.

My Server looks like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8200, '192.168.0.127', function() {
  console.log('Server listening...');
});

io.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('init', data);
});
```

And since Ionic is friends with AngularJS my Client Controller looks like this:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, ServerUrl) {

  var socket = io.connect(ServerUrl.serverUrl()); // ServerUrl: 'http://192.168.0.127:8200'

  socket.on('init', function(data) {
    // something
  });
```

I included the Socket.IO Client script in my index.html head like this:

```
<script src="lib/socket.io/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

When I remote debug the app it throws this repeatedly with different t parameters:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE     http://192.168.0.127:8200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1431079993172-0
```

I've thoroughly searched every related question on here but they didn't solve my problem. I really need this thing to work and would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your smartphone running on its own **internet** or on the **lan** that is connected to desktop;

Comment: @vijay, from the sample, it looks like it is on a LAN. But that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @farshad90, Try providing the absolute path while including `socket.io.min.js`.

Comment: @vijay it was an IP address issue. `192.168.0.127` was the WiFi IP of my desktop but somehow everytime i connected my smartphone to my desktop to deploy the app a LAN network was build and the WiFi Adapter was disconnected so `192.168.0.127:8200` was out of reach. Deactivated the LAN network and everything works fine. Thank you guys for the hints.

Comment: @keval if it was not IP address issue it could have been definitely library's path as issue.thanks

Comment: Glad to know you found the solution. Please add an answer so that it'll help someone if they find such an issue.

Comment: @vijay oh I forgot to mention I did change the library path and that didn't help so I think it was the IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an IP address issue. 192.168.0.127 was the WiFi IP of my desktop but somehow everytime I connected my smartphone to my desktop to deploy the app a LAN network was build and the WiFi Adapter was disconnected so 192.168.0.127:8200 was out of reach. Deactivated the LAN network in Windows Control Panel and everything works fine.